# want to create multiple tables at one shot in bigqery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I want to create multiple tables at one shot in bigquery. Table definition is like as follows(teradata) and could u please suggest me what i need to achieve this ,and how i need to define keys in bigquery.

```
CREATE  TABLE   LME_TABLES_DB.AD_AGNCY_ORG              

        (           
            AD_AGNCY_NBR    VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC 
 NOT NULL,          
            PARENT_ADVERTISING_AGENCY_NUMB  VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN 
 NOT CASESPECIFIC,            
                            AD_AGNCY_NM VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT 
 CASESPECIFIC,            
            PARTY_ID    INTEGER,                    
            PARTY_SUBTYPE_CD    CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT 
 CASESPECIFIC,            
            ORG_TYPE_CD CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,            
            CREATE_DTTM TIMESTAMP(6),                   
            UPDT_DTTM   TIMESTAMP(6),                   
            CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC       
        )           
        UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX    XPKAD_AGENCY_ORGANIZATION   (   
 AD_AGNCY_NBR,ORG_TYPE_CD);
```

Comment: hi @Mikhail Berlyant I have seen your kind responses are very nice . I just want to create the teradata table definition(which is mentioned above ) in bigquery

Comment: You need to use the UI or API since BigQuery does not support `CREATE TABLE` statements yet.

Comment: thanks for ur response how I can use API to write  the above query could u please explain me @Elliott Brossard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery does not support [SQL Data Definition Language (DDL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language), instead you must create a table using the UI, `bq` command-line tool, or API. Here, I'll provide an example of how to use the [`bq` command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool) to create a table.

Use the `bq mk` command to create a table. You can specify the schema as a command-line argument.

```
bq mk -t LME_TABLES_DB.AD_AGNCY_ORG AD_AGNCY_NBR:STRING,PARTY_ID:INT64
```

See the [reference documentation on BigQuery data types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types) for a list of supported types.

You could alternatively specify a path to a JSON file defining the schema. The schema file follows the same format as [configration.load.schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.schema) in the Jobs API.

*See also: the official docs on [how to create a table in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#create-table).*

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response @Tim Swast.what exactly we want is like we are migrating the existing  data(Teradata fully structured data) to google cloud (Bigquery database) we have existing data say historical data we need to dump that historical data into new cloud datawarehouse. say for example we created a table in bigquery called AD_AGENCY_ORG as ur response to my question after creating how we need to load the data from teradata to bigquery is there any tool for that or what we need to do to achieve this kindly explain me step by step